# How to format setInterval output in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm creating a cubing timer using JS. The way my timer works looks like this:

`javascript`:

```
// Timer
let = [milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
let timeRef = document.querySelector("#timer");
let int = null;

function StartTimer() {
    if (int !== null) {
        clearInterval(int);
    }
    int = setInterval(displayTimer, 10);
}

function ResetTimer() {
    clearInterval(int);
    [milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours] = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    timeRef.innerHTML = '0.00';
}

function StopTimer() {
    clearInterval(int);
}

function displayTimer() {
    milliseconds += 10;

    if (milliseconds == 1000) {
        milliseconds = 0;
        seconds++;
        if (seconds == 60) {
            seconds = 60;
            minutes++;
            if (minutes == 60) {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
            }
        }
    }
    let h = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
    let m = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    let s = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    let ms = milliseconds < 10 ? '00' + milliseconds : milliseconds < 100 ? '0' + milliseconds : milliseconds;
    timeRef.innerHTML = `${s}.${ms}`
}

// Running Timer by pressing Space bar
let state = 'stopped';

const transitions = {
  waiting: state => ResetTimer(),
  started: state => StartTimer(),
  stopped: state => StopTimer(),
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', changeState);
document.addEventListener('keyup', changeState);

function changeState({code, repeat, type: action}){

  if(code !== 'Space' || repeat){
    return;
  }
  
  // this allows to have more event types and states in the future without cluttering
  const actions = {
    keydown: () => state === 'stopped' ? 'waiting' : 'stopped',
    keyup: () => state === 'stopped' ? state : 'started',
  };
   
  const next = actions[action]();
  next === state || transitions[state = next](state);
  
}
```

`html`:

```
<body>
    <div class="scramble-bar">{{scramble}}</div>
    <div id="time">
        <div id="timer">
            0.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

It's a solution from internet. Now I want to format output of setInterval from looking like this: `01.230` to this: `1.23`. I want to remove zeros from both sides. Zero in the end doesn't even change, it always stays zero. At the start it looks like in html `0.00`. but when it starts, it becomes `00.000`. I've already changed something in Timer, so don't get confused if something looks illogical.

And one more problem is displaying minutes and hours. Actually, I would like to display them, but only if it gets to the point of displaying them. If seconds > 60, I want to add minutes to the timer. If minutes > 60, I want to add hours. Currently, when it comes to 60 seconds, it starts again from `00.000`. (`59.990 -> 00.000`).

How can I do it?

Comment: The formatting isn't the biggest issue here. Your current code will not count time accurately, since `setInterval` doesn't _guarantee_ that the function is called exactly `interval` milliseconds between; furthermore, it takes time to execute the function too. For accuracy, you'll need to compute the difference between the current time and the timer's start time instead of incrementing milliseconds yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment: The formatting isn't the biggest issue here. Your current code will not count time accurately, since `setInterval` doesn't *guarantee* that the function is called exactly `interval` milliseconds between; furthermore, it takes time to execute the function too. For accuracy, you'll need to compute the difference between the current time and the timer's start time instead of incrementing milliseconds yourself.

Here's a version that does that (with a bit less logic in the state-changing function, so just hitting any key will stop and start the timer) and with formatting more like what you probably want.

```js
// Timer
let startTime = 0;
let timeRef = document.querySelector("#timer");
let int = null;

function startTimer() {
  if (int !== null) {
    clearInterval(int);
  }
  int = setInterval(displayTimer, 10);
  startTime = +new Date();
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(int);
}

function divmod(a, b) {
  return [Math.floor(a / b), a % b];
}

function displayTimer() {
  const totalMs = Math.round((+new Date()) - startTime);
  const [totalS, ms] = divmod(totalMs, 1000);
  const [totalM, s] = divmod(totalS, 60);
  const [h, m] = divmod(totalM, 60);
  let formatted = "";
  if (h > 0) formatted += `${h} h `;
  if (m > 0) formatted += `${String(m).padStart(2, "0")}:`;
  formatted += `${String(s).padStart(2, "0")}.${String(ms).padStart(3, "0")}`;
  timeRef.innerText = formatted;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', changeState);

function changeState(event) {
  if (int) stopTimer();
  else startTimer();
}
```

```html
<div class="scramble-bar">{{scramble}}</div>
<div id="time">
  <div id="timer">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks nice, but. Can you tell me which function resets timer? And can I remove that 0 from seconds `0`0.000 if seconds < 10?

Comment: `startTimer` resets the timer because it sets `startTime` , the reference time. And sure, you can do whatever you like - look at how the `displayTimer` function works to format the time components and change it accordingly.

Comment: I changed `formatted += ${String(s).padStart(1, "0")}.${String(ms).padStart(2, "0")};`. Now it shows `1.23->1.231->1.232->...->1.24->1.241`. It makes 2-digit ms only when 3rd digit is 0. How can I fix that?

Comment: Oh, one more problem. When it gets to one minute, it displays like that: 01:`1`.123. I need to change displaying seconds when minute > 0

Comment: That's why it's `padStart(2, "0")` in my code. Read up on what `padStart` does, try it out, and you'll get how this works.